# What is the best way to display HTML content on a Windows Form?

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to display an HTML formatted content in my application preferably inside a Web Browser control.

I could create an HTML document first and then load it in the Web Browser control, but that is just too clumsy.

Is there any way I can load a string that contains HTML code directly into the Web Browser?

```
String = "<b>Hello</b> World"
```

Expected output: **Hello** World

I'm using Visual Basic 9 (VS2008).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this by dragging a `WebBrowser` control onto your application and then adding the following code:

```
 webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<b>Hello</b> World";
```

Comment: What happens if you get "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment."

Comment: @MarkLakata see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783863/activex-control-8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2-cannot-be-instantiated-be

Answer (score 4):

You can open the document object in the Web Browser control then:-

```
document.write("<b>Hello</b> World");
```

Comment: This will only work if the web browser object is currently navigated somewhere.  Otherwise the document property will be null.

Comment: @JaredPar: he could navigate to "about:blank"