# ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment

Tags: vb.net, browser, activex

I am getting this error when i try to show a form with an webbrowser in it.

**ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment**

I am calling it by:

```
Public Class frmMain
  Class Server
       Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim aTcpMessaging As IMessagingSystemFactory = New TcpMessagingSystemFactory()
        Dim anInputChannel As IInputChannel = aTcpMessaging.CreateInputChannel(theIPforLocal & ":" & thePort)
        Dim aStringMessagesFactory As IStringMessagesFactory = New StringMessagesFactory()
        Dim aStringMessageReceiver As IStringMessageReceiver = aStringMessagesFactory.CreateStringMessageReceiver()
        AddHandler aStringMessageReceiver.MessageReceived, AddressOf StringMessageReceived

        aStringMessageReceiver.AttachInputChannel(anInputChannel)
    End Sub

       Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived()
            Call New frmMM().Show()
       End Sub
  End Class

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RelState As Integer = 0
    Call frmMain.Server.Main()
    lblVer.Text = "V.7"
    Pid = 0
  End Sub
End Class
```

How can i load this up so it doesn't show me that error?

Thanks.

David

**Code update**

```
 Class Server
    <STAThread()> Public Sub Main()
        Dim aTcpMessaging As IMessagingSystemFactory = New TcpMessagingSystemFactory()
        Dim anInputChannel As IInputChannel = aTcpMessaging.CreateInputChannel(theIPforLocal & ":" & thePort)
        Dim aStringMessagesFactory As IStringMessagesFactory = New StringMessagesFactory()
        Dim aStringMessageReceiver As IStringMessageReceiver = aStringMessagesFactory.CreateStringMessageReceiver()
        AddHandler aStringMessageReceiver.MessageReceived, AddressOf StringMessageReceived

        aStringMessageReceiver.AttachInputChannel(anInputChannel)
    End Sub

   Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived()
        Call New frmMM().Show()
   End Sub
 End Class

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RelState As Integer = 0
    Call frmMain.Server.Main()   '<-- the error now
    lblVer.Text = "V.7"
    Pid = 0
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class Server
<STAThread()> Public Sub Main()
    Dim aTcpMessaging As IMessagingSystemFactory = New TcpMessagingSystemFactory()
    Dim anInputChannel As IInputChannel = aTcpMessaging.CreateInputChannel(theIPforLocal & ":" & thePort)
    Dim aStringMessagesFactory As IStringMessagesFactory = New StringMessagesFactory()
    Dim aStringMessageReceiver As IStringMessageReceiver = aStringMessagesFactory.CreateStringMessageReceiver()
    AddHandler aStringMessageReceiver.MessageReceived, AddressOf StringMessageReceived

    aStringMessageReceiver.AttachInputChannel(anInputChannel)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived()
  Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ShowFP)

  t.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
  t.Start()
 End Sub
End Class

Private Shared Sub ShowFP()
  Dim ShowFP As New frmFPVid
  ShowFP.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem happens because a UI component is being created on a non-UI thread.
Here is a simplified version of code which will break with this error message.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Private _ThreadedProcesss As ThreadedProcess
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _ThreadedProcesss = New ThreadedProcess()
        _ThreadedProcesss.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Class ThreadedProcess
        Private _thread As System.Threading.Thread

        Public Sub Start()
            _thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadEntryPoint)
            _thread.Name = "Testing thread"
            _thread.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub ThreadEntryPoint(status As Object)
            Dim wb As New WebBrowser()
            wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            wb.Visible = True
            wb.DocumentText = "Hello world"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

To correct the problem, you just need to get back to the UI thread before creating the control.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Private _ThreadedProcesss As ThreadedProcess
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _ThreadedProcesss = New ThreadedProcess(New EventHandler(AddressOf ThreadedProcess_Create))
        _ThreadedProcesss.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadedProcess_Create(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
            Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf ThreadedProcess_Create), {sender, e})
        Else
            Dim wb As New WebBrowser()
            Me.Controls.Add(wb)
            wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            wb.Visible = True
            wb.DocumentText = "Hello world"
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class ThreadedProcess
        Private _thread As System.Threading.Thread
        Private _callback As EventHandler

        Public Sub New(callback As EventHandler)
            _callback = callback
        End Sub

        Public Sub Start()
            _thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadEntryPoint)
            _thread.Name = "Testing thread"
            _thread.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub ThreadEntryPoint(status As Object)
            _callback.Invoke(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

So for your example I believe the code would be:

```
 Class Server
    Private _callback as EventHandler
    Public Sub Main(callback as EventHandler)
        _callback = callback
        Dim aTcpMessaging As IMessagingSystemFactory = New TcpMessagingSystemFactory()
        Dim anInputChannel As IInputChannel = aTcpMessaging.CreateInputChannel(theIPforLocal & ":" & thePort)
        Dim aStringMessagesFactory As IStringMessagesFactory = New StringMessagesFactory()
        Dim aStringMessageReceiver As IStringMessageReceiver = aStringMessagesFactory.CreateStringMessageReceiver()
        AddHandler aStringMessageReceiver.MessageReceived, AddressOf StringMessageReceived

        aStringMessageReceiver.AttachInputChannel(anInputChannel)
    End Sub

    Private Sub StringMessageReceived()
        _callback.Invoke(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub
  End Class

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Dim RelState As Integer = 0
      Call frmMain.Server.Main(new EventHandler(AddressOf Server_MessageReceived))   '<-- the error now
      lblVer.Text = "V.7"
      Pid = 0
  End Sub
  Private Sub Server_MessageReceived(sender as Object, e As EventArgs)
      If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
          Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf Server_MessageReceived), {sender, e})
      Else
          Call New frmMM().Show()
      End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not using the application framework, you need to decorate your `Sub Main` with the [STAThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx) attribute.

For example:

```
<STAThread()> _
Public Sub Main()
```

VB Applications that use the application framework do not have to worry about this attribute since the compiler will apply it automatically.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of this? I also updated the code in the OP to show a shared function that i forgot to include the first time around.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer to show what I mean. I assume that you have a Sub Main in the application?

Comment: I cant seem to call the main() anymore. The part **Call frmMain.Server.Main()** no longer works and has an error of **Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.**

Comment: Is the `frmMain.Server.Main` your main entry point for the application?

Comment: I've updated my OP. Hopefully someone will know what to do in order to correct it.

Comment: Still need help with this :o)

Answer (score 1):

Just searched myself silly, since I am not really doing any threading myself, but I found a solution to my problem with the same error.

Anyway, you also will get this error: "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment" when you try to use an object on a form (with the WebBrowser Control on it) when that form has not been created yet.

fyi